# ActiveMQ broker not starting

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm trying to start an ActiveMQ broker, I currently have JDK 1.8.0_31 and ActiveMQ 5.11.1 installed. When I run activemq from the bin folder in my ActiveMQ installation I get the following message:

```
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_31 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre
Heap sizes: current=1005056k  free=984084k  max=1005056k
JVM args: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xms1G -Xmx1G - Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\activemq\bin\..\conf\login.config -Dactivemq.classpath=C:\activemq\bin\..\conf;C:\activemq\bin\../conf;C:\activemq\bin\../conf; -Dactivemq.home=C:\activemq\bin\.. -Dactivemq.base=C:\activemq\bin\.. -Dactivemq.conf=C:\activemq\bin\..\conf -Dactivemq.data=C:\activemq\bin\..\data -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\activemq\bin\..\data\tmp
Extensions classpath:
[C:\activemq\bin\..\lib,C:\activemq\bin\..\lib\camel,C:\activemq\bin\..\lib\optional,C:\activemq\bin\..\lib\web,C:\activemq\bin\..\lib\extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: C:\activemq\bin\..
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: C:\activemq\bin\..
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: C:\activemq\bin\..\conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: C:\activemq\bin\..\data
Usage: Main [--extdir <dir>] [task] [task-options] [task data]

Tasks:
    browse                   - Display selected messages in a specified destination.
    bstat                    - Performs a predefined query that displays usefulstatistics regarding the specified broker
    create                   - Creates a runnable broker instance in the specified path.
    decrypt                  - Decrypts given text
    dstat                    - Performs a predefined query that displays usefultabular statistics regarding the specified destination type
    encrypt                  - Encrypts given text
    export                   - Exports a stopped brokers data files to an archive file
    list                     - Lists all available brokers in the specified JMXcontext
    purge                    - Delete selected destination's messages that matches the message selector 
    query                    - Display selected broker component's attributes and statistics.
    start                    - Creates and starts a broker using a configuration file, or a broker URI.
    stop                     - Stops a running broker specified by the broker name.

Task Options (Options specific to each task):
    --extdir <dir>  - Add the jar files in the directory to the classpath.
    --version       - Display the version information.
    -h,-?,--help    - Display this help information. To display task specific help, use Main [task] -h,-?,--help

Task Data:
    - Information needed by each specific task.

JMX system property options:
    -Dactivemq.jmx.url=<jmx service uri> (default is: 'service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi')
    -Dactivemq.jmx.user=<user name>
    -Dactivemq.jmx.password=<password>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: getting any exceptions?

Comment: No, I just installed ActiveMQ 5.2 instead, and it started working. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to pass a second command line parameter to start the broker.

```
activemq console
```

This runs the broker in the foreground, or if you want to run it in the background:

```
activemq start
```

To stop

```
activemq stop
```

Comment: Yep, it turns out at the time of this comment [their instructions for Windows](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html#GettingStarted-OnWindows:) forget to mention that you need to specify any command line parameters (though they mention it for starting ActiveMQ on Unix).

Answer (score 0):

I just installed ActiveMQ 5.2 instead, and it started working. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, ActiveMQ requires Java 7 (current version, Apache ActiveMQ 5.11.1). See [Pre-Installation Requirements](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html#GettingStarted-Pre-InstallationRequirements)

Then, the Jake's answer works for me (pass a second command line): activemq start

Answer (score 0):

For ActiveMQ 5.15.8 Release
   you can start using commnad

```
./Bin>activemq start
```